# Installation failed when trying to install Firebase app

Tags: android, firebase, fastlane

I'm trying to build and upload my android app to **Firebase**.

**I'm using CircleCI, fastlane and fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution.**

Currently, it is building and uploading to Firebase but after Downloading the app, I receive a message **'Installation failed'**

CI (fastlane and fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution) output

```
[15:58:50]: ---------------------------------------
[15:58:50]: --- Step: firebase_app_distribution ---
[15:58:50]: ---------------------------------------
[15:58:50]: Authenticating with --service_credentials_file path parameter: ./google-services-private-key.json
[15:58:50]:  Authenticated successfully.
[15:58:50]: ⌛ Uploading the APK.
[15:58:56]: ✅ Uploaded APK successfully and created release 1.0 (1).
[15:58:56]: ✅ Posted release notes.
[15:58:57]: ✅ Added testers/groups.
[15:58:57]:  App Distribution upload finished successfully.

+------+---------------------------+-------------+
|                fastlane summary                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform          | 0           |
| 2    | assemble                  | 124         |
| 3    | firebase_app_distribution | 7           |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

[15:58:57]: fastlane.tools finished successfully 
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

And this is my lane (Fastfile)

```
  desc "Upload to Firebase"
    lane :upload_firebase do
      gradle(
        task: "assemble"
      )

      firebase_app_distribution(
        app: 'APP-ID',
        groups: 'my-group',
        release_notes: "Release",
        firebase_cli_path: "/usr/local/bin/firebase",
        firebase_cli_token: ENV['FIREBASE_CI_TOKEN'],
        service_credentials_file: './google-services-private-key.json'
      )
  end
```

And in CI I execute the lane: `bundle exec fastlane upload_firebase`.

I googled about this but I couldnt find anything useful.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Be sure that you are a part of the group, "my-group". Check your email that you logged in AppTester.